# Compare the text array and the input array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an array of text and an array of fields, I need to implement so that when a user enters a value in a field, the value is compared with the text for this field. I.e., for example, the number "12" is written in one text field, and the user entered "13" and "Not correct" was output to the log, and there are 6 such fields and text. (this is the solution of the number 6+6=12) Please tell me how to do it better, I started doing this:

```
    public InputField[] Inputfield1;
    public Text[] text1;

    public void CurBtn()
    {
  foreach (InputField inputField in Inputfield1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < text1.Length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < Input_Numer_1.Length; j++)
                    {
        
                        if (text1[i].ToString() == Inputfield1[j].text)
                        {
                             Debug.LogFormat($"OK");
                        }
else{
 Debug.LogFormat($"Not correct");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It looks like you outer `foreach` can be removed, but other than that, what are you looking for here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Text` is a [`UnityEngine.Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) and [`Object.ToString`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.ToString.html) basically returns the `GameObject`s name like [`Text.name`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-name.html).

You rather would want it's [`UI.Text.text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Text-text.html)

```
if(text1[i].text == Inputfield1[j].text)
```

However, why not rather actually store `int` values and use `int.TryParse` to convert your user input to a numeric values and rather compare `int` based which is way more efficient.

---

You also have one loop to much there .. currently you iterate the inputs twice.

To me it sounds like you don't even want to compare each input to each text but rather have certain pairs of both you want to compare like

```
[Serializable]
public class CheckPair
{
    public InputField Input;
    public Text Text;

    public bool Compare()
    {
        var correct = Text.text == Input.text;

        Debug.Log($"{correct ? "" : "NOT "} correct", Input);

        return correct;
    }
}
```

And in the Inspector rather assign these in a single

```
public CheckPair pairs;
```

and then

```
public void CurBtn()
{
    foreach (var pair in pairs)
    {
        pair.Compare();
    }
}
```

or if you e.g. want to know if all are correct

```
public void CurBtn()
{
    foreach (var pair in pairs)
    {
        if(!pair.Compare())
        {
            Debug.Log($"{pair.Input} is not correct!");
            return;
        }
    }

    Debug.Log("All are correct!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! can you also tell me please how to check all the fields for emptiness? I write like this: if (pair.Input.text==string.Empty) { Debug.Log("All input empty!"); }. But for some reason nothing is output(

Comment: I would use linq (`using System.Linq`) and do `if(pairs.All(pair => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pair.Input.text)){ ... }`